# How to add profile image to side menu in swift ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have side menu using tableview and it works well but i don't know how to add a circle profile image to the side menu in swift. Please help me how to do this.here is my code,

```
  override function tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell
    var cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1") as? UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell!.frame.size.width, cell!.frame.size.height))
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView
    }
    cell!.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
    cell!.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row];

    var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 10, 20, 20));
    var image = UIImage(named:images[indexPath.row]);
    imageView.image = image;
    cell!.imageView?.image = imageView.image

    return cell!
}
```

Thanks

Comment: yes it possible, You can make there using "viewForHeaderInSection"

Comment: Can you send me code please

Comment: your question is unclear, please add code/images of explain more about what you have or what in you project have you tried doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{
        return 70 // Please change its according to you 
 }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
    var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 70))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    var profileImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(40, 5, 60, 60)) // Change frame size according to you ..
    profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "image name") //Image set your
    view.addSubview(profileImageView)

    return view
}
```

It will work fine .. change minor according to you

Comment: heyy how to create slidebar menu in swift without using storyboard in ios please help me

Comment: Try this may be help full.. http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

Answer (score 0):

You can use

Objective c

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection (NSInteger)section
{
   UIView *headerView = // the size of the header you want
   UIImageView *userImageView = // the size of the UserImage you want
   userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = userImageView.bounds.size.width/2;
   userImageView.image = // the userImage
   [headerView addSubView:userImageView];
   return headerView;
}
```

Swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
    var headerView = UIView( // size you want
    var userImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(// size you want)) 
    userImageView.image = // user image
    userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = userImageView.bounds.size.width/2'
    headerView .addSubview(userImageView )
    return headerView 
}
```

Don't forget to set the height of the header accordingly

Comment: you need to add a label with the imageView